# If every infinite subset of E has a limit point in E then E is closed and bounded

Tags: real-analysis

Im looking to clarify a step in a prove regarding this theorem. Hoping to have my ideas reviewed: 
This is regarding E as a set in $R^k$.

> If every infinite subset of E has a limit point in E then E is closed and bounded

Proof:

> If E is not bounded, then for each n = 1, 2, . . . there is a point $x_n$ ∈ E with
>   |$x_n$| > n. This infinite set has no limit point, a contradiction.

**Attempt at explanation of the above:**

Suppose the above infinite set did have a limit point y, then that point must have some distance d = |y| (distance from origin). Pick the nearest integer n that d is less than ($ceiling(d)$) and call it $N_1$. Then take the min distance, m,  of y to all the $x_n$ such that n < $N_1$. This can be done since the set of n < $N_1$ is finite.

Then take the epsilon ball off radius less than m about y, this ball will not intersect any $x_n$ for n < $N_1$. To avoid any $x_n$ greater than $N_1$ we must take the $ceiling(d)$ and take the epsilon ball of less than distance = $min(m,ceiling(d))$.

This epsilon ball will not intersect any $x_n$, hence y cannot be a limit point.

> If E ⊂ R is not closed then there is a point p ∈ R which is a limit point of E but not in
>   E. Thus, for each n = 1, 2, 3, . . . there is a point $x_n$ ∈ E with |$x_n$ − p| < 1/n. This set
>   S = {$x_1$, $x_2$, . . .} has p, not in E, as its only limit point. Contradiction.

**Attempt at an explanation of the above:**

Suppose there was a limit point, x, and it lied in E. Then x has some distance to p. Then x is within some distance 1/$n_1$ to p for some greatest integer $n_1$. We can follow a similar argument to my previous argument in finding a radius that avoids all $x_n$ for n < $n_1$ then avoid then next closest 1/n distance similarly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think these are needless since the explanations in yellow are pretty clear themselves.

Comment: I think your explanations are okay.  But whom exactly are you explaining *to* and *why*?  Yourself?  Then, yes, you have explained the proofs correctly.  Someone else?  Than I have no idea if the person will be able to follow your explanations or not?  As the proofs were supposed to be complete and not require any further explanation, I have no idea what was confusing the person and I have no idea if you explanation addresses this hypothetical confused person's concerns.

Comment: Just explaining it to myself, just to make sure i had the right idea. Thank you